# Tracing non-uniform slowdown on a multisite install with multiple domains

Tags: multisite

I've got a multisite install. By default, new sites are on subdomains. The host is not the fastest, but given the price, not too bad.

Recently, I updated the install to use extra domains. The domains are parked as add ons to the main install. I changed the base link and domain for the sites I wanted to use new domains with and added a quick redirect to the .htaccess so I don't have to worry about old links. The time to the first byte is 10 to 20 seconds but only for the new domains.

*Clarification: I had `example.com` and `site2.example.com` which now redirects to `site2.com` which is the domain that WP has been told is the root path for the site.*

I've checked with customer support and the domains are definitely resolving at the same speed as the main domain. It is not plugin related because even sub-sites using few if any plugins are the same and the problem is not there for subdomain subsites.

What are the areas I should investigate to try and find a solution?

Comment: Questions need to be specific and answerable in a way that everybody who has this question sees the answer and it is the solution, not just a reply that was the most useful to you, but the authorative answer for all people all time. This question looks like an open ended investigation or a request for advice/discussion. Your problem is not specific, lots of people have your setup and do not encounter the lag you're reporting, you need to investigate to discover your actual problem before you can ask how to solve it

Comment: That's my problem. I do not know how or where to investigate.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus it more sharply on the "Where do I even look"? part of the question as the full question has, according to @Tom J Nowell, the answer in the form of, "no not a known bug, I don't know how to fix it so this must be too broad, and where should you look? Not here, that's where."

Comment: I guess you need to work out what's happening for those 10-20 seconds: is it WordPress or is it Apache, and is it just one single web request or are you getting redirected around many times first? Ideally I suppose you'd run a profiler on PHP to find out what's going on, but I don't know if that's possible in production (or at all).

Comment: It might also be worth checking what's happening for the database for these requests, whether it's making loads of requests and / or rebuilding permalinks or something.

Comment: @Rup I have edited to add clarity as per your first comment.  I think I know a development tool plugin that might help me profile things. I'll give that a look.

Comment: Where to look is still too open ended, it has to be specific, which means someone would need to write an answer that labelled all the places to look, in their entirety, such that no other places could be looked in. Such an answer would be huge and need to cover hundreds of edge cases in order to be canonical. Open ended questions don't fit into the stack exchange format. In your situation the very concept that there is a specific place to look in that holds the information you seek does not make sense. Performance is just too vague and ambiguous without narrowing it down

Comment: TLDR: The core of this question is "My X is slow, how do I discover cause Y?" which is a huge open ended subject with no authorative canonical answer, so it doesn't fit the site. Unless you find the cause and ask how to fix it, the Q can't be fixed